# Task hang infinitely when calling .Wait() in kafka-net

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-net

I'm currently trying to post messages from a for-loop on a kafka server running on my local machine using the kafka-net library in c# (https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net), following the example given on the linked repo, my code is the following.

```
string kafkaServer = "http://" + ip + ":" + port;
Uri uri = new Uri(kafkaServer);
var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);
var router = new BrokerRouter(options);
var client = new Producer(router);
...
foreach(string sumup in LS){
    payloadJson["fullPathDataFolder"] = remoteFolder;
    payloadJson["globalName"] = GloablName;
    payloadJson["name"] = name;
    payloadJson["text"] = sumUp + "\n";
    payloadJson["type"] = type;
    string payload = payloadJson.ToString();
    KafkaNet.Protocol.Message msg = new KafkaNet.Protocol.Message(payload);
    client.SendMessageAsync(topic, new List<KafkaNet.Protocol.Message> { msg }).Wait();
}
```

This code run through the first iteration and i'm able to retrieve the first string from a second machine linked to the same server with a consumer.
Then the code here above remain stuck at the intruction:

```
client.SendMessageAsync(topic, new List<KafkaNet.Protocol.Message> { msg }).Wait();
```

If now I remove the .Wait() this code run quite fast but it randomly ignore some of the string i send
What am I missing ?

P.S.
I'v tried also to use Confluent.kafka and i got similar problems

P.P.S.
It's important that this program run sequentially.

Comment: I'm not familar with Kafka and it's details. However I know calling .Wait on tasks can cause deadlock issues. Try using ConfigureAwait(false)  on the task object before calling wait

Comment: If you can't `await` it, use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.Wait()`

Comment: Can you post your Confluent.Kafka version? (not sure kafka-net is still maintained...)

Comment: @zeroid I've removed that packet from my project so I don't know now but i installed is using the instruction on the official website so it should have been the last one

Comment: @Dave Thank you, I'm currently trying, for the moment, no loss and no deadlock but i can't tell if it's luck or if it's actually working

Comment: @SilvioZanoli always hard to tell with these things unfortunately.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I've tried to use what you said but it get stuck anyway

Comment: I have the same problem. Have any solution?